# How to petition to have a Stack Exchange Site closed

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, vote-to-close

There are some communities that are completely bogus.

For example, the "interpersonal skills" community will only allow questions that pertain to light hearted subjects and are easy to answer unobjectively.

Anything that will describe trauma, or difficult questions involving complex social issues will be closed as either off topic or subjective.

Does this website pride itself on it's apathy and ignorance?

Comment: Sorry Adam, but this reads more like a frustrated rant, regardless of the fact that it's applicable only to one site, and hence off-topic here. If you have any grievances about how your question was handled, please bring it up *constructively* on their meta, and anything else is not likely to achieve any favorable result for either side.

Comment: I'm afraid I must question the wisdom of editing an eight-month-old, poorly-received post just to reintroduce a typo that someone else already corrected.

Comment: Well it got upvoted and so I go a notification for that, and Grammarly recommended the addition of the comma

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no standard process in place to petition for a Stack Exchange site to be closed. The closest thing there is to that is what you're doing right now by asking on Meta. However, I need to stress that it is *exceptionally* unlikely that anything will come of this. If a site has serious problems, there are numerous steps that can be taken to try to improve the overall quality of the site before such a drastic measure as complete closure would ensue. The state of IPS is not so bad that it needs to be completely *closed*.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to be part of a community that doesn't live up to your expectations, there's a simple solution: [delete your account](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current).

You can't petition to have a Stack Exchange site closed, just like you can't petition to dissolve a sovereign country whose inhabitants you don't like.

Comment: I mean, you can. Through various communication channels, including writing "Please close {site}" on a letter and mailing it to the SE offices in NYC. You just likely won't suceed in getting your way.