# Don't let users enter a sixth tag in the first place

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

Yes, in the fine print it says "Add up to 5 tags".

Then don't let users enter a sixth tag. Currently it is like Cheech & Chong, "[Don't take those. I already took them.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CUxCpcayKo)".

Once the above is implemented people won't be able to post photos like:

[image: Math problem]

In fact, how I could have possibly taken such a screenshot would be a moot question. (OK, I removed the sixth, but the janitor was still out to lunch for many seconds.)

Comment: It's Not a Bug, It's a Feature.

Comment: Update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4bf5573a-cce7-4bf3-9ca7-387d28c45871/view-source

Comment: @DanJacobson that's a different question, seems worth asking separately. Despite the negative score you are ahead in rep with this one.

Answer (score 17):

Seems like the way it works now wastes less time than disallowing the adding of a sixth tag.

Let's suppose like most users you're not sure what tags to add.

Currently you can add as many tags as you like, look at them together, decide which ones are the most important and delete the least important or relevant.

If we only allow a maximum of 5 tags to be present, yes we stop that red message appearing but...

If you want to add another tag you have to delete one of the ones you already have in order to add a new one. If that newly added tag wasn't as good as the tag you just deleted you have to delete it, remember the name of that tag that you just deleted and then add that one back again.

Comment: @DanJacobson Please read: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](/q/44188) and [Common reasons why your meta post may be negatively received](/q/333476) before filing your next feature request.