# Why have you hidden the "Data Explorer" tool?

Tags: feature-request, design, data-explorer

Why is Data Explorer tool accessed only by clicking the word "Data" at the bottom of the page?

Correct it.

1. Change the word **"Data"** to **"Data Explorer"**.
2. Bring the word **"Data Explorer"** high up so it can be seen as soon as a visitor comes to StackExchange.com

Comment: It would be good to include a mobile layout sample and another sample for desktop, as this would enrich your post. You can use your own browser to modify SE pages using DevTools to make visual changes to be suggested.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to find, but do we need to waste valuable space at the top of the page on a feature used by a tiny percentage of users?

Comment: So, in summary, your proposal is to remove user participation data from the layout and replace it with a link to the Data Explorer? Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to Meta! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 9):

> Why is Data Explorer tool accessed only by clicking the word "Data" at the bottom of the page?

Because the domain it links to is `data.stackexchange.com`.

The naming scheme is consistent in the UI with API which links to `api.stackexchange.com`

The tool is technically not called Data Explorer. Its name is Stack Exchange Data Explorer, often shortened to SEDE.

I don't think the link needs to change. The name covers what you would expect when clicking on it: You get to a site where you can work with Data. If you wish you can explore existing queries or write your own queries to get new insight on Data.

Comment: "*The name covers what you would expect when clicking on it: You get to a site where you can work with Data.*" On that note, if I didn't know what a "Data Explorer" was, then putting that name on the link would not help me in any way. If I knew about Data Explorer, then a link called "Data" should ring a bell for me.