# Are users being suspended for being on strike?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension, moderation-strike

Does Stack Exchange suspend users solely for striking or supporting [the strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an?noredirect=1&lq=1)? Of course, users who are on strike could still be suspended for unrelated activities, or for promoting the strike in unacceptable ways, but is SE suspending users *because* they are on strike?

Comment: Punish people who stopped volunteering by... preventing them from volunteering? How exactly would that work?

Comment: @DanMašek many users who are on strike are still asking and answering, just not moderating.

Answer (score 28):

Nope. So far as from what I can tell, from what I see offsite, and what I see on this site and others I moderate, there's been no reports of people being suspended *specifically* for being on strike.

Technically being rude and abusive is a related activity for some, but as one of the two sites that's likely the lightning rod for drama on the network, there have been no suspensions for *striking in general*.

Comment: Sorry, what sort of strike are we talking about?

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an)

Answer (score 6):

No, this has not happened. No one has been suspended for reasons related to the strike.